# How to port cgal library to android

Tags: android, c++, linux, cmake, cgal

The CGAL Library comes with several demo programs, written in C++ and using Qt4/Qt5 and OpenGL. I want to port these demo programs on a device running Android.

Comment: Do you already have a C++ cross-compiler? What did you try?

Comment: I suspect that porting anything that uses Qt to Android will be back-breakingly difficult. On Linux, Qt uses X (maybe Wayland these days), or perhaps direct access to the framebuffer device. I don't think Android will allow an unprivileged program direct access to the framebuffer device, even if the hardware provides one. Although there are X servers for Android, to build Qt you would first have to build all the Xlib dependencies -- a horrible task. I would happy to be proven wrong about this, because I can think of a number of Qt programs I would like to port to Android. But it looks nasty.

Comment: @KevinBoone Qt5 has [a builtin Android support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html).

Comment: @Irineau: Wow. Is that documented somewhere? What is the mechanism of access to the display hardware?

Answer (score 2):

See the wiki entry about that topic: [Cross Compilation of CGAL for Android](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/Cross-Compilation-of-CGAL-for-Android).

The process is slightly easier using a new version of CGAL: [4.11-beta2](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/~lrineau/CGAL-4.11-beta2/).